# Qt Data Receiving on i2c line

Tags: qt, interrupt, i2c

I want to get data from i2c line but data sending time is unknown it means I dont know when data come in to my card  and as far as I know in qt there is no interrupt so how can I detect the data in qt.

Answer (score 0):

in Qt you have slots as an analog of interrupts. But in Qt you won't work directly with i2c line. Look here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/49096/i2c-bus-control-using-qt-qml/2

Comment: In order to use slot function I have to put emit signal so where I should put  emit signal